# PHP/SQL Join four tables where two table rely on another

Tags: php, sql, join

I'm very stuck and have tried multiple way to resolve this with no luck.
I'm pretty new to PHP and SQL.
I have four tables that I'm trying to get a while loop to retrieve data from. My biggest problem is that two of the tables have an id that relate to another and I can't echo the team names for the Away Team.

These are my tables:

Table 1

> **Away_Team**
>   Team_ID, Away_Team_ID

Table 2

> **Home_Team**
>   Team_ID, Home_Team_ID

Table 3

> **Teams**
>   Team_Name, Team_ID

Table 4

> **Fixture** 
>   Away_Team_ID, Home_Team_ID ,     Date

```
<?php
 $data_s = $conn->query('SELECT Teams.Team_Name, Home_team.Home_Team_ID, 
 Home_team.Team_ID 
 FROM Teams
 JOIN Home_team ON Teams.Team_ID = Home_team.Home_Team_ID
 JOIN Fixtures ON Fixtures.Home_Team_ID = Home_team.Home_Team_ID
 UNION ALL
 SELECT Teams.Team_Name, Away_team.Team_ID, Away_team.Away_Team_ID 
 FROM Teams
 JOIN Away_team
 ON Teams.Team_ID = Away_team.Team_ID
 JOIN Fixtures ON Fixtures.Away_Team_ID = Away_team.Away_Team_ID;’} ?>
```

My While loop:

```
<?php
echo "<table border=1>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Home Team</th>
            <th>Away Team</th>
            <th>Score</th>
        </tr>" 

while($records = $data_s->fetch()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $records['Date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $records['Team_Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $records['Team_Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $records['Home_Score'] . "-" . $records['Away_Score'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
} 
echo "</table>" ?>
```

I don't know how to get my second team Name to echo the Away team name that relates to that fixture.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if you have control over the database layout, but it seems that this could be made simpler if the only the `Teams` and `Fixtures` tables were used. Why do you need the `Away_team` and `Home_team` tables?

Comment: Where are the scores (Home_Score and Away_Score) coming from?

Comment: I agree, it's hard to understand the purpose of the Home Team and Away Team tables. Surely the team which is home and away is defined in the fixtures table already. These other tables would seem to be redundant.

Comment: I through many to many tables are not very good to normalisation. Have I got that wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you are trying to do with the output (and assuming that the scores come from the Fixtures table), I think you should be starting with the Fixtures table and joining to that i.e.

```
SELECT Date, 
    (SELECT Team_Name FROM Teams WHERE Teams.Team_ID = Home_Team.Team_ID) As Home_Team,
    (SELECT Team_Name FROM Teams WHERE Teams.Team_ID = Away_Team.Team_ID) As Away_Team,
    Home_Score,
    Away_Score
FROM Fixtures
JOIN Home_Team ON Home_Team.Home_Team_ID = Fixtures.Home_Team_ID
JOIN Away_Team ON Away_Team.Away_Team_ID = Fixtures.Away_Team_ID
```